# how to add type annotation to pseudo-classical class with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a pseudo-classical class here:

```
function Car(numWindows: number) {
  this.numWindows = numWindows;
}
```

and I was wondering how I can type the property `this.numWindows` since I'm getting an error message `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)`. I was hoping to do this for this example without using ES6 classes. Also, when trying to instantiate Car with the `new` keyword, I get this:

```
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're writing new code in use the `class` keyword. There are ways to make this work but they are awkward

Comment: Why don't you use class? It seems `class` is what exactly you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add some rather hacky type trickery (it can be done in many ways, but this is one way):

```
interface IPseudoClass<Args extends any[], T> {
  new (...args: Args): T;
}

const PseudoClass = <Args extends any[], Class>(constructor: (...args: Args) => Class) =>
  constructor as any as IPseudoClass<Args, Class>;

interface ICar {
  numWindows: number;
}

const Car = PseudoClass(function(this: ICar, numWindows: number) {
  this.numWindows = numWindows;
  return this;
});

const myCar = new Car(4);

console.log(myCar.numWindows); // 4
```

Or you can (as you should) use an actual class instead. Like this:

```
class Car {
  public numWindows: number;
  constructor(numWindows: number) {
   this.numWindows = numWindows;
  }
}

const myCar = new Car(4);

console.log(myCar.numWindows); // 4
```

Comment: thanks for answering my actual question especially since I explicitly added the stipulation that I'd like to do this without the class keyword. I also learned that this is passed as the first argument in such a construct, similar to how self is in python in the process. That, and how TypeScript isn't amenable to this particular pre-ES6 way of building classes